# Working Days in DAX

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a requirement where I need to find the working days of a store. The formula to find the working days of a store is:-

If Store is opened on or before first day of respective month then

**Working Day = Total Days in a month.**

If Showroom is opened in middle of respective month then

**Working Day = Last Date Of month - Opening Date Of Showroom.**

Please note that For current calendar month we should consider Today()-1 as Last date of month.

Store Data

[image: Store Date]

Date Table

[image: Date Table]

Required Result

[image: Required Result]

```
=CALCULATE(SUM('Showroom Master'[W]),FILTER(ALL('DateMaster'),DATESBETWEEN('Date Master'[Date],FIRSTDATE('Showroom Master'[OPENINGDATE]),LASTDATE('Date Master'[Date]))),USERELATIONSHIP('Showroom Master'[OPENINGDATE],'Date Master'[Date]))
```

Another Solution

```
=CALCULATE(SUM('Showroom Master'[W]),USERELATIONSHIP('ShowroomMaster'[OPENINGDATE],'Date Master'[Date]),
DATESBETWEEN('Date Master'[Date],FIRSTDATE('Showroom Master'[OPENINGDATE]),LASTDATE('Date Master'[Date])))
```

Calculation [W]

```
=(TODAY()-1)-'Showroom Master'[OPENINGDATE]
```

Since both Showroom and Date are master tables I cannot have directly relationship between the two.

So anybody have a solution of it

Regards,
Piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt get a DAX query to solve this issue, instead I have added a new table in the model which solves my purpose.
If anyone got the solution please post it here.